# How to set figures and tables captions in APA style (without using APA6 class)

Tags: tables, graphics, captions, apa-style, apa6

As one can see in the given link, APA style requires a very special format for captions in [figures and tables](http://psych.utoronto.ca/users/reingold/courses/resources/handouts_apa/TablesFigures1.pdf).

How can I realize this in standard article format? (I do not want to use the APA6 class due to its restrictions made for papers)

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{tikz}

\title{Test}
\author{Me, myself and I}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Table section}

\begin{table}[htpb]
\caption{The caption of table is not APA formatted yet.}
\begin{flushleft}
\small
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
Column 1 & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Column 2} \\
& Column 2a & Column 2b & Column2c \\
\hline
1 & 1 & .67 & 5 \\
1 & 2 & .32 & 2 \\
1 & 3 & .01 & 4 \\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\multirow{2}{90mm}{Note: The caption is not APA formatted yet.}} \\
\\
\end{tabular}
\end{flushleft}
\end{table}

\section{Figure section}

\begin{figure}[htpb]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (2, 3);
\draw (0,0) -- (0, 3);
\draw (2,3) -- (0, 3);
\draw (0,3) -- (10, 1.5);
\draw (10, 1.5) -- (2, 3);
\draw (10, 1.5) -- (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{The caption of figure is not APA formatted yet.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To set-up the captions use the `caption` package, together with `setspace` to cope with the double spacing requirement for figure captions.  Now you can use `\captionsetup[table]` and `\captionsetup[figure]` to define the styling of captions for the two environemnts.  There are hooks for the different fonts involved, the justification of the text and the formatting of the label relative to the text.  The package documentation contains a number of good examples.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{multirow,booktabs,setspace,caption}
\usepackage{tikz}

\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator*{spaced}{\\[2ex]}
\captionsetup[table]{textfont=it,format=plain,justification=justified,
  singlelinecheck=false,labelsep=spaced,skip=0pt}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=period,labelfont=it,justification=justified,
  singlelinecheck=false,font=doublespacing}

\begin{document}

\section{Table section}

\begin{table}[htpb]
\caption{The caption of the table.}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\toprule
Column 1 & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Column 2} \\
& Column 2a & Column 2b & Column2c \\
\midrule
1 & 1 & .67 & 5 \\
1 & 2 & .32 & 2 \\
1 & 3 & .01 & 4 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\small\textit{Note}. The caption should now be correctly formatted.
\end{table}

\section{Figure section}

\begin{figure}[htpb]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (2, 3);
\draw (0,0) -- (0, 3);
\draw (2,3) -- (0, 3);
\draw (0,3) -- (10, 1.5);
\draw (10, 1.5) -- (2, 3);
\draw (10, 1.5) -- (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{The caption of figure is long to demonstrate the desired
double spacing which is a specific requirement of the style.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```